# Why is my Minecraft chat invisible?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have accounts for my two kids. The eldest, age 7, has a laptop. The youngest, 5, has a PC that hosts a multiplayer LAN game. We can join no problem, I can use my own account no problem. However, on the 5-year-old's PC, he can't chat or see any chat at all. I've done exhaustive Googling and playing with the chat settings. **Chat is on Shown.**

However, chat is simply not showing up. We can use console commands and they work, but we get no system message. If I type something on the PC (5 y/o) account, the laptop can see it, but we (the speaker) cannot. It's as if chat *works*, but is *invisible*. I'm sure the kid has done something because I often find him playing in the settings. Does anyone have an idea how to get chat to show even if invisible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

- Either in game (Esc) or on the main menu press 'Options'
- Press 'Chat Settings'
- Make sure Opacity is 100% and Scale is 100%

If it's what I think it is, then this will fix it. And If you wish, you can change both settings to what you prefer.

Comment: In Windows 10, this is under Settings, Video, toward the bottom. It didn't solve my problem, though.

Answer (score -3):

It is a  bug that is blocking chat and it will happen more in older versions of Minecraft.
If you completely shut down the game and reopen it and it should help.